# Can't install glibc and glibc-common cause they need each other

Tags: rhel, rpm, libraries, dependencies

I am working on RHEL 7.2 and I want to install LibXp.so.6 and LibXmu.so.6, but I have problem with glibc-common-2.17-105.el7.x86_64.rpm and glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686.rpm because they need each other.

```
[root@hostname ~]# rpm -i glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686.rpm
warning: glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key  ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        glibc-common = 2.17-105.el7 is needed by glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686
        libfreebl3.so is needed by glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686
        libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) is needed by glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686
[root@hostname ~]# rpm -i glibc-common-2.17-105.el7.x86_64.rpm
warning: glibc-common-2.17-105.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    glibc = 2.17-105.el7 is needed by glibc-common-2.17-105.el7.x86_64
```

How should I install this? I don't have connection to the internet so I can't use yum, only rpm.

What's more, I think these libraries are installed:

```
[root@hostname ~]# rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-common-2.17-105.0.1.el7.x86_64
glibc-2.17-105.0.1.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: Try installing them both together, i.e. `rpm -i glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686.rpm glibc-common-2.17-105.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: ok, i know it is stupid but i didnt realize its possible to install few rpm's at once... thanks, it works! Now i have a couple conflicts cause i have istalled a newer lib but i will solve it by my own.

Comment: Not at all -- we all have to start somewhere!  I'll add this as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Where packages are co-dependent you need to install them together like this:

```
# rpm -i glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686.rpm glibc-common-2.17-105.el7.x86_64.rpm
```